# Is there a better way to test Node.js application with ElasticSearch?

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch, testing, tdd

If use Ruby on Rails framework, we can run the test in a easy way. It can create a test database, and we can make some fake data. After all the test finished, the test database will be cleaned.

Now want to do the same test with Node.js, Express framework and ElasticSearch. If create index data in the real ES server, maybe not the good way(Think ES as development environment used). Is there a better way to do it as RoR above?

I have researched from internet, but didn't find good example.

Comment: If you use docker, you can dynamically start an elastic search for your builds.

Comment: @bezerra Do you mean use docker to run different containers for ES?

Comment: Yes, you can deploy a ElasticSearch instance in docker container and populate data as you do normally. Then, after tests finished, destroy the container.